# How to use xapian which returns a URL when indexing a web page

Tags: python-2.7, search-engine, xapian

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, Python 2.7

My code for getting the contents from a given URL:

```
def get_page(url):
'''Gets the contents of a page from a given URL'''
    try:
        f = urllib.urlopen(url)
        page = f.read()
        f.close()
        return page
    except:
        return ""
    return ""
```

To filter the content of a page provided by `get_page(url)`:

```
def filterContents(content):
'''Filters the content from a page'''
    filteredContent = ''
    regex = re.compile('(?<!script)[>](?![\s\#\'-<]).+?[<]')
    for words in regex.findall(content):
        word_list = split_string(words, """ ,"!-.()<>[]{};:?!-=/_`&""")
        for word in word_list:
            filteredContent = filteredContent + word
    return filteredContent

def split_string(source, splitlist):
    return ''.join([ w if w not in splitlist else ' ' for w in source])
```

How to index the `filteredContent` in `Xapian` so that when I query, i get returned the `URLs` the query was present in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely clear what your `filterContents()` and `split_string()` are actually trying to do (throwing away some HTML tag contents and then word splitting), so let me talk through a similar problem that doesn't have that complexity folded into it.

Let's assume we have a function `strip_tags()` which returns just the textual content of an HTML document, and your `get_page()` function. We want to build up a Xapian database where

- each document represents the resource representation pulled from a particular URL
- the "words" in that representation (having been passed through `strip_tags()`) become searchable terms that index those documents
- each document contains as its [document data](http://xapian.org/docs/apidoc/html/classXapian_1_1Document.html#b1b0da2e7c76acd754f29a52e14f89ae) the URL it was all pulled from.

So you could index as follows:

```
import xapian
def index_url(database, url):
    text = strip_tags(get_page(url))
    doc = xapian.Document()

    # TermGenerator will split text into words
    # and then (because we set a stemmer) stem them
    # into terms and add them to the document
    termgenerator = xapian.TermGenerator()
    termgenerator.set_stemmer(xapian.Stem("en"))
    termgenerator.set_document(doc)
    termgenerator.index_text(text)

    # We want to be able to get at the URL easily
    doc.set_data(url)
    # And we want to ensure each URL only ends up in
    # the database once. Note that if your URLs are long
    # then this won't work; consult the FAQ on unique IDs
    # for more: http://trac.xapian.org/wiki/FAQ/UniqueIds
    idterm = 'Q' + url
    doc.add_boolean_term(idterm)
    db.replace_document(idterm, doc)

# then index an example URL
db = xapian.WritableDatabase("exampledb", xapian.DB_CREATE_OR_OPEN)

index_url(db, "https://stackoverflow.com/")
```

Searching is then simple, although it can obviously get more sophisticated if needed:

```
qp = xapian.QueryParser()
qp.set_stemmer(xapian.Stem("en"))
qp.set_stemming_strategy(qp.STEM_SOME)
query = qp.parse_query('question')
query = qp.parse_query('question and answer')
enquire = xapian.Enquire(db)
enquire.set_query(query)
for match in enquire.get_mset(0, 10):
    print match.document.get_data()
```

which will display 'https://stackoverflow.com/', since 'question and answer' is on the homepage when you aren't logged in.

I'd recommend checking out the [Xapian getting started guide](http://getting-started-with-xapian.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) both for concepts and code.

Comment: THanks a lot for ur time and help. How about displaying both the contents of a page and the URL?

Comment: Get to grips with the concepts of Xapian. You can put anything you want in document data, for instance; the correct way of approaching this will depend on your situation & what you're doing, so I cannot give specific advice.